# Two different colors in a same datalabel VBA

Tags: vba, colors, charts, label

I have a chart on excel with a curve. The curve represents the price of a stock depending of the time (so basically I've a column A full of dates and Column B full of prices and a chart).

Now for each point in the chart there is a datalabel text as followed

```
Charts("CHART").SeriesCollection(1).Points(Numpoint).DataLabel.Text = numcomptagesetup & vbCrLf & numcomptagecountdown
```

"numpoint" is a variable that goes from point 1 to the last one.
"numcomptagesetup" and "numcomptagecountdown" are values that goes from 1 to 6 for "numcomptagesetup" and from 1 to 15 for "numcomptagecountdown".

The code above is writing "numcomptagesetup" then jumping two lines then writing "numcomptagecountdown"

What I need is, depending on 2 signals, to change the color of "numcomptagesetup" in green or red and the color of "numcomptagecountdown" in green and red too. So in some cases, I'll need to have two different colors in the same datalabeltext.

I've written this loop and it works at least at the beginning (step by step method) then everything change and the colors aren't at the good place (red instead of green or the contrary) ... Really strange
By default, all the points are green, then i change the color of the point to red when I want :

```
 For numpoint=1 to 100
With Charts("CHART").SeriesCollection(1).Points(Numpoint)
            .HasDataLabel = True
            .DataLabel.Text = numcomptagesetup & vbCrLf & numcomptagecountdown
            .DataLabel.Font.Size = 6
            .DataLabel.Font.Color = vbRed
            .MarkerSize = 5
End With
If Signal = 2 Then Charts("CHART").SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Select 
  With Charts("CHART").SeriesCollection(1).Points(Numpoint).DataLabel.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 3).Font.Fill 
    .Visible = msoTrue 
    .ForeColor
    .RGB = RGB(0, 176, 80) .Solid 
  End With 
End If

If Signal2 = 2 Then
    Charts("CHART").SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Select
    With Charts("CHART").SeriesCollection(1).Points(Numpoint).DataLabel.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(4, 1).Font.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 176, 80)
        .Solid
    End With
End If
```

I hope you understand my problem ! If not you can ask, i'll answer as quickly as I can

Thank you!!

Comment: for starters this is not a loop (or perhaps you need to provide more of your code)  :)  Also, please note that the `ForeColor.RGB` you assign in both of the cases for `Signal2=2` and `Signal=2` is the same.

Comment: i've edited the code : The with/end with is getting the textlable in red by defaut (for the upside and downside part), then the two if conditions conduct to put in green the upside part or the downside part of the textlabel or both

Comment: When I try to run simlar code, what happens to me is that ALL data points get the same formatting, even though I explictly loop over each datalabel in the series... I will look a little more and see what I can find out.

Comment: I'm stumped. Even the macro recorder creates code very similar to yours (excpet it `Select` the datalabel). I tried doing that, but still, applies the color to every datalabel in the series, not just the selected datalabel.

Comment: Haha you have understood my problem :) I don't know where this problem comes from and I did a little research but I've found nothing on the subject

Comment: I have a possible solution that you can try, I will post an answer shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am stumped by this. Even the macro recorder gives me code similar to yours, but when I run it, the color is applied to *all* datalabels in the Series.DataLabels.

I have a possible workaround, which would be to add TextBox shapes to the chart, and to position them directly on top of the data labels. Then, remove the datalabels at the end.

```
'## This is from your original code:
For numpoint=1 to 100
    With Charts("CHART").SeriesCollection(1).Points(Numpoint)
        .HasDataLabel = True
        .DataLabel.Text = numcomptagesetup & vbCrLf & numcomptagecountdown
        .DataLabel.Font.Size = 6
        .DataLabel.Font.Color = vbRed
        .MarkerSize = 5
    End With
Next

'## Now, I make some changes:
Dim srs As Series
Dim dl As DataLabel
Dim dlText As String

Set srs = Charts("CHART").SeriesCollection(1) '## I find it easier to work with objects, so I use variable "srs"

'## Delete any textboxes that might be leftover from previous.
For Each shp In cht.Shapes
    shp.Delete
Next

For Each dl In srs.DataLabels  '## object-oriented programming, use a DataLabel object variable :
    dlText = dl.Caption
    '## Add a textbox to overlay the datalabel
    Set tb = cht.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, dl.Left, dl.Top, dl.Width, dl.Height)
    With tb.TextFrame2
        .VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle
        .WordWrap = msoFalse
        .AutoSize = msoAutoSizeShapeToFitText
        With .TextRange
            .Text = dlText
            .Font.Size = dl.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size
            '## Apply character color format to the textbox:
            If Signal = 2 Then
                With .Characters(, 3).Font.Fill
                    .Visible = msoTrue
                    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 176, 80)
                    .Solid
                End With
            End If
            '## Apply character color format to the textbox:
            If Signal2 = 2 Then
                With .Characters(4, 1).Font.Fill
                    .Visible = msoTrue
                    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 176, 80)
                    .Solid
                End With
            End If
        End With
    End With
Next

'## Finally, turn off the datalabels that you don't need anymore.
srs.HasDataLabels = False
```

Comment: First thank you to help me ! Secondly, I'm translating this in my sub (because the signal is different for each point so I have to delete the "for each") and then I'll give you some news :)

Comment: It's working great ! Thanks a lot !! I just have a little problem to center the textbox on each point : I use 
For i = 1 To 90
    ActiveChart.Shapes.Range(Array("TextBox " & i)).Select
    Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementLeft -4.2
Next i

But the "-4.2" doesn't work every time. I think there's no code like this for a textbox which isn't link to a point :
Charts("CHART").SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Position = xlLabelPositionCenter

If you have any idea, i'll be glad to here it.
Else thank you !

Comment: Yes I meant to set cht = charts ("chart"). I can try to help with the other questions but probably can't look at it for s few hours.

Comment: I had an idea :

For numpoint=1 to 100
    With cht.SeriesCollection(1).Points(Numpoint)
        .HasDataLabel = True
        .DataLabel.Text = numcomptagesetup & vbCrLf & numcomptagecountdown
        .DataLabel.Font.Size = 6
        .DataLabel.Font.Color = vbRed
        .MarkerSize = 5
    End With
Next

 Cht.SeriesCollection(1).Points(numpoint).DataLabel.Position = xlLabelPositionCenter

then the same code as you wrote! 
So basically, we create some datalabels on the points, then with the new line of code, we center them and then we take their position and transfer it to the textbox.

Comment: But It doesn't work and I don't know exactly why. If you have some time you could look (don't hesitate to write it in an other answer so that I can vote for your answer ;) )

Comment: My will is to find a way to have the perfect match in term of position between the textbox and the points. A command wich will allow me to center the textboxes automatically.                                     
But if it doesn't exist I can stay with the manual method (i.e    ActiveChart.Shapes.Range(Array("TextBox " & i)).Select Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementLeft -4.2 )

Comment: I wonder if the `.AutoSize = msoAutoSizeShapeToFitText` is conflicting. After that line, try to put two more lines: `tb.Left = dl.Left` and `tb.Top = dl.Top`. Ultiamtely it might not be exact, there are unfortunately some things about data labels that will not align 100% accurately with text boxes/etc.

Comment: Thank you for your help David! Everything works great thanks to you

Answer (score 0):

i've come up with something else :

```
 With ChartObj.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Font.fill                                    
         .TwoColorGradient msoGradientDiagonalUp, 1
         .GradientAngle = 45
         .GradientStops(1).Position = 0 '.2
         .GradientStops(2).Position = 1 '0.8
         .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
         .BackColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
 End With
```

wich gives me a gradient color for the datalabels.